# Is it possible to not render hidden elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a website which has two diffrent kind of menus, depending on the screen width of device. I use `display: none` to hide the menu. I would like to not include the hidden elements in the DOM if they are not needed.

I tried to write js script to remove them, but I cannot do it before the page loads. I wonder if it is possible to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you generating the html?  Is it static .html files?  php?  C# MVC?

Comment: Not necessary on client side. Hidden elements arent rendered... And if you remove them, it would be better to do this on serverside, as the only improvement would be loading speed.

Comment: javascript will work once the DOM is loaded or at least javascript code is loaded. In your case you can simple hide the menu  using css class and remove the element using js and then remove css class. So user will not notice change in the menu

Comment: it is more right to do that job with a backend scripting language but if you want to remove that elements you can add a unique class and remove it when dom state is interactive. (if i didn't get the question wrong)

Comment: if you want them gone before the page loads you have to control it on the server side. Although I don't really see the harm in just having them hidden in the source, unless there's something confidential in there that the current user should not have any chance of discovering.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think I will just have it hidden in the source.